# Passing multiple child components as parameter

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

So using the component would look like this:

```
<ParentListComponent Header="Test">
   <ChildListItemComponent Name="1"/>
   <ChildListItemComponent Name="2"/>
   <ChildListItemComponent Name="3"/>
   <ChildListItemComponent Name="4"/>
</ParentListComponent>
```

And the `ParentListComponent` would look something like this:

```
@foreach(var childComponent in listComponents){
    @childComponent
}

@code{

   [Parameter]
   Public List<ChildListItemComponent> listComponents { get; set; }
}
```

I know I could easily render it by passing it as ChildContent like shown below, but I'd really like to keep the list so I can easily access each item from the parent.

```
[Parameter]
public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
```

I feel like I'm just missing the syntax here, but unfortunately I can't find the info for this. If you can help I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Templated component might be the way to go, see the docs [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/templated-components?view=aspnetcore-3.1). The examples shown use both a table and an unordered list, but the basics are the same. You get dynamically rendered content based on a list either way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'd create a `ParentComponent` and a `ChildComponent`. The mark-up for `ParentComponent` would have the following

```
<CascadingValue Value=this>
@ChildContent
</CascadingValue>

@code
{
  [Parameter]
  public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

Now your children will have access to the parent, like this

```
[CascadingParameter]
public ParentComponent ParentComponent { get; set; }
```

In the `OnInitialized` method you can call `ParentComponent.RegisterChild(this);` and in `IDisposable.Dispose` you can call `ParentComponent.UnregisterChild(this);`

Those are two methods you would add yourself on your parent class to keep a list of ChildComponent.

There's a full walk-through on Blazor University [here](https://blazor-university.com/templating-components-with-renderfragements/creating-a-tabcontrol/).

Comment: I can't accept your answer, so I'll only up-vote it. Thank you...;)

Comment: I'd forgotten that CascadingValue existed, thank you :)